# Disabling GCM push notification

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I use GCM push notification for my Android app which is basically an instant messenger like Line/What's App. In my app, even after the user logs out, the push notification continue to happen. IN other words, I have no control over the notifications.

Ideally, I would like the notifications to stop when the user logs out of the app and resume after he logs in. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should share a bit how you implement the push notifications,
What you have tried already to make them stop and didn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `SharedPreferences`.

You should have a preference that contain the value if the user should be alerted or not.
Let's say, once a user logged out - set the preference value to false.
Now,in your GCMIntentService in the `onMessage` method, check the value of the preference, if its false, just do nothing.

Have a look at this example:

[How to use SharedPreferences in Android to store, fetch and edit values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

Comment: Brilliant! I forgot I was creating a notification upon reception of GCM message...

Answer (score 5):

Call This Method `GCMRegistrar.unregister(context);` when the user signs out to stop receiving the push messages.

Comment: Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
startService(unregIntent);                                                                                                               I saw this code from google to unregister my device, Any way how to use this

Answer (score 1):

You have to unregister your app to avoid receiving further push notifications. You can use GCMRegistrar.unregistrar() to make this happen.

Answer (score 0):

As Google unregister() method was deprecated, instead use the  `InstanceID.deleteInstanceID()`.